# My function doesn't work

Tags: php, youtube, explode

I would like to store youtube video id-s and names in my database, but on the admin page, I just want to send the video link in a form.

I tried this, but it doesn't work. I'm just learning how to use a function. Would you please help me?

```
if (isset($_POST['sendit'])){
$y_video  = $_POST['video'];
function video_add($y_video){

        $video=explode("=", $y_video);
        $code = explode("&",$video[1]);
        $video_feed = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=".$video[1]."&max-results=1&fields=entry(title)&prettyprint=true");
        $video_obj = simplexml_load_string($video_feed);
        $video_str = $video_obj->entry->title;
        $sql="INSERT INTO youtube ('y_vid','y_nev')
        VALUES('".$code[0]."','".mysql_real_escape_string($video_str)."')";
        mysql_query($sql);
            header("Location:video-list.php");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the function but you are not calling it. You should edit your code to look something like this:

```
<?
  function video_add($y_video){

        $video=explode("=", $y_video);
        $code = explode("&",$video[1]);
        $video_feed = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=".$video[1]."&max-results=1&fields=entry(title)&prettyprint=true");
        $video_obj = simplexml_load_string($video_feed);
        $video_str = $video_obj->entry->title;
        $sql="INSERT INTO youtube ('y_vid','y_nev')
        VALUES('".$code[0]."','".mysql_real_escape_string($video_str)."')";
        mysql_query($sql);
            header("Location:video-list.php");
  }

  if (isset($_POST['sendit'])) video_add($_POST['video']);
?>
```

So basically, you first create the function (you can put it in some other file which you would later include if you need it on multiple places) and then you call it with the data you received with post.

Also, you are lacking connection data (or maybe you omitted those on purpose).

Also **do not use mysql_* since they are deprecated. Use mysqli_* or PDO**. See more at http://php.net/mysql_query

Comment: Thank you, that's great. The new problem is, that the header:location happens, but there's nothing in the database :S

Comment: Well are you missing connection data?

Comment: No,it's on the top of the page :S

Comment: Then first remove the `header()` for now, and after mysql_query() add `echo mysql_error()`. This should let you know what the error is, and why the data is not being inserted.

Comment: I found it :) The '' was the problem here:('y_vid','y_nev') Thank you for everything Mr. :)